# netDxf .net library Read and write AutoCAD dxf files

Tags: c#, dxf

I try this [netDxf .net library](https://netdxf.codeplex.com/) programmed in C# to read and write AutoCAD dxf files.

I need in this moment only read AutoCAD dxf file from the web server without success because I don't have error but only white and empty webpage.

How to do resolve this ?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance, my code below.

```
    DxfDocument allImages = DxfDocument.Load("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\web220000.dxf");
    int counter = 1;
    foreach (netDxf.Entities.Image image in allImages.Images)
    {
        DxfDocument doc = new DxfDocument();
        netDxf.Entities.Image copy = (netDxf.Entities.Image)image.Clone();
        doc.AddEntity(copy);
        string fileName = string.Format("Image{0}.dxf", counter++);
        doc.Save(fileName);
    }
```